# A set with positive Lebesgue Measure and not Borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

I know that Lebesgue measure is completion of Borel measure and there is zero Lebesgue measured set that is not Borel measurable. However I could not be sure that is there any set with positive Lebesgue measure which is not Borel measurable.

I appreciate for any explanation or suggest etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a non-Borel measurable null set and take a disjoint union with a set of positive Lebesgue measure. The result will have positive Lebesgue measure and not be Borel measurable.